# Singular and plural mess-up for an algorithm

Tags: grammatical-number, terminology, technical, technology

How do I define a term and then use it in singular or plural context?

Here is the problem:

I am looking for a word which would collectively define the parameter setting for all the parameters in an algorithm.

Currently, I have defined a parameter setting as follows:

> A parameter setting for an algorithm is defined as a set of values representing a specific value for each parameter in the algorithm.

What I mean is the set [a, b, c], where a, b, and c are the corresponding values of parameters A, B, and C for an algorithm.

I feel this definition is ambiguous, as "parameter setting" can mean a setting for a particular parameter in an algorithm (not for the set).

Answer (score 1):

Then what you need is a term that implies plurality while being singular. I'd go for something like *parameter set* or *parameter group*. This allows for three levels: *parameter* → *parameter group* → *parameter groups*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **vector**.

In computer programming, a one-dimensional array.
http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/vector.html

It correctly describes a row of values.

**Examples**

[Defining a very long parameter vector](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-IML-Software-and-Matrix/Defining-a-very-long-parameter-vector/td-p/148598)

[Estimation of a parameter vector when some components are restricted](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X02000453)

[Approximate Riemann Solvers, Parameter Vectors, and Difference Schemes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.457.5978&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: In computer programming, isn't a vector a special kind of data structure, which may or may not be what the parameter settings are stored in? If they're not actually stored in a vector in the particular program we're talking about, using that term would be confusing.